# Objective-c regex to check phone number

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

How to validate a phone number (NSString *) in objective-c? Rules:

- minimum 7 digits
- maximum 10 digits
- the first digit must be 2, 3, 5, 6, 8 or 9

Thanks

Comment: Objective-C itself is a very minimal language that barely does anything for you — certainly not regular expressions. It's much more relevant to say what libraries you're using (Cocoa, Cocoa Touch, POC, etc).

Comment: My phone number begins with a 0 in the UK or a +44 when I am abroad.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use a regular expressions library (like RegexKit, etc), or you could use regular expressions through `NSPredicate` (a bit more obscure, but doesn't require third-party libraries).  That would look something like this:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = ...;
NSString *phoneRegex = @"[235689][0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})?"; 
NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex]; 
BOOL matches = [test evaluateWithObject:phoneNumber];
```

If you're on iPhone, then iOS 4 introduced `NSRegularExpression`, which would also work.  The `NSPredicate` approach works on both Mac and iPhone (any version).

Comment: Just had to one-up me, didn't you :)

Comment: It doesn't even work across the whole US, so I'd assume the OP has a precisely narrow use case he's dealing with.

Comment: Yes, it's a specific narrow use case I am looking for.

Comment: What is the meaning of the '?' (last char of phoneRegex)?

Comment: It means "none or one" of the last group.  Conceptually, you'd probably think of the optional digits as coming at the beginning for a 10- vs 7-digit phone number, but since you have a requirement on the first digit, it's easiest to call the last three digits the optional ones.

Answer (score 24):

**Please don't use your own regex for the phone-number. Don't**.

The format of phone numbers changes across the country, and your app might be used outside of your own country.

Instead, use what Apple provides, as Josh says. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTextCheckingResult/phoneNumberCheckingResultWithRange:phoneNumber:).

Answer (score 11):

For those searching for phone extraction, you can extract the phone numbers from a text, for example:

```
NSString *userBody = @"This is a text with 30612312232 my phone";
if (userBody != nil) {
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:userBody options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [userBody length])];
    if (matches != nil) {
        for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
            if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber) {
                DbgLog(@"Found phone number %@", [match phoneNumber]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Is it possible to extract number in international format using NSDataDetector?

Answer (score 7):

The [`NSDataDetector`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, available in iOS 4.0 and later, is a specialized subclass of `NSRegularExpression` that has explicit support for detecting phone numbers.

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 4.0+ there are built in classes to do this, [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber)

In everything else you can either use a 3rd party RegEx library, or use an [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) if your needs are narrow enough