# NSPredicate for mobile number validation

Tags: ios, xcode, nspredicate

How to validate a phone number (NSString *) by NSPredicate?

Rules:

minimum 10 digits

maximum 10 digits

the first digit must be 7,8 or 9
Thanks

Comment: Very similar : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3349494/767730

Comment: @Anupdas:vote to close :)

Comment: It was similar but not up to the mark as required. thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `NSPredicate` based on a regular expression will fit your requirements.

```
NSString *stringToBeTested = @"8123456789";

NSString *mobileNumberPattern = @"[789][0-9]{9}";
NSPredicate *mobileNumberPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", mobileNumberPattern];

BOOL matched = [mobileNumberPred evaluateWithObject:stringToBeTested];
```

You don't need to keep the pattern in a string by itself, but regexes are complicated enough already so it makes the overall code clearer if you keep it out of the `NSPredicate` format string.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use below code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;   // return NO to not change text
 {
  if(textField.tag == 111)
    {
    if([self MobileNumberValidate:string] == TRUE)
    return YES;
    else
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Mobile Number validation
- (BOOL)MobileNumberValidate:(NSString*)number
{
NSString *numberRegEx = @"[0-9]";
NSPredicate *numberTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", numberRegEx];
if ([numberTest evaluateWithObject:number] == YES)
    return TRUE;
else
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: @iBhavin bolo ibhavin

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *phoneNumber = @"1234567890";
    NSString *phoneRegex = @"[789][0-9]{3}([0-9]{6})?"; 
    NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex]; 
    BOOL matches = [test evaluateWithObject:phoneNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work for your requirement:

Function:

```
-(BOOL)validatePhone:(NSString *)enteredPhoneNumber
{
    NSString *phoneRegex = @"[789][0-9]{9}";
  // OR below for advanced type 
  //NSString *phoneRegex = @"^((\\+)|(00))[0-9]{6,14}$";

    NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex];

    return [phoneTest evaluateWithObject:enteredPhoneNumber];
}
```

Call it:

```
if ([self validatePhone:@"9833112299"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Valid Phone Number");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Invalid Phone Number");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Make it Global using 'extension' use it wherever required

In any one of your view controller class at the **end after last }** paste below code

```
extension String
{
func validateMobile() -> Bool
{
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@","[789][0-9].{9}").evaluate(with: self)
 }
 }
```

when you want to validate yourTxtField in any ViewController class simply call as below:

```
if (yourTxtField.text?.validateMobile())!
{
 print("It is 10 digit, starting with 7/8/9")
}
else
{
 print("Invalid mobile number")
}
```