# Validating user input from a regEx

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I have to validate phone no from following regEx.

```
//**regExpPattern** : "+?[0-9]{0,3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}( |-)?[0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{3}"
-(BOOL) textFieldValidation:(NSString *)checkString withRegEx:(NSString*)regExpPattern
{
      NSString *stringToValidate = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:checkString];
      NSString *pattern = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:regExpPattern]
      NSLog(@"%@ %@",checkString,regExpPattern);


      NSPredicate *myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",pattern];

            if ([myTest evaluateWithObject:stringToValidate]){
                return YES;
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
```

I'm getting the following exception :

'**NSInvalidArgumentException**'
'Can't do regex matching, reason: (Can't open pattern U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX (string 6789054321, pattern +[?][0-9]{0,3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}( |-)?[0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{3}, case 0, canon 0))'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349494/objective-c-regex-to-check-phone-number

Comment: A simple one.. If this could help: http://www.iossnippet.com/snippets/validation/how-to-validate-a-phone-number-in-objective-c-ios/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is a special character; you need to escape it (`\+?`) or use it properly (e.g. `\s+?` for leading spaces)

Answer (score 0):

**Use the pattern like this**

```
regExpPattern=@"(([+]{1}|[0]{2}){0,1}+[1]{1}){0,1}+[ ]{0,1}+(?:[-( ]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-) ]{0,1}){0,1}+[ ]{0,1}+[0-9]{2,3}+[0-9- ]{4,8}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem too. '+' is indeed a meta character,you should understand why you use '+'.

If you want to match '+' like a normal character.then you should use '\+'.

If you treat the '+' like special character,want to match one other character.then you should add the character before '+',then it will not crash.

PS: in iOS predicate the 'like' and 'matches' do not conform same regex match rule!